# Using GetMetadata in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I"m a beginner in LLVM.

I'm trying to add metadata to instructions. I tried to work around with the following code from [LLVM-Source Level Debugging](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html):

```
if (MDNode *N = I->getMetadata("dbg")) {  // Here I is an LLVM instruction
        DILocation Loc(N);                      // DILocation is in DebugInfo.h
        unsigned Line = Loc.getLineNumber();
        StringRef File = Loc.getFilename();
        StringRef Dir = Loc.getDirectory();
}
```

What is the data type of `I` in `I->getMetadata("dbg")`? How should I define `I`?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I` is an `Instruction`. In general, throughout the LLVM codebase, documentation and code samples,

- `I` is an [`Instruction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html)
- `F` is a [`Function`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html)
- `M` is a [`Module`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html)

For more information about the high-level structure of LLVM modules and how to get access to instructions, see

- [High-level structure of LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#high-level-structure)
- [Basic inspection and traversal routines](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#basic-inspection-and-traversal-routines)

Comment: Thank you :) Can you tell me for example how should  I initialize Instruction *I? I want a concrete example, that I'm not able to find.

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer just open the code or documentation for the instruction you want to create. For example, if you want to create a [`ret` instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#ret-instruction), you can use one of [its `Create` static methods](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ReturnInst.html), for instance `ReturnInst* I = ReturnInst::Create(C);` where `C` is the current context (you can get the context from the module).